# 3D world in Java using lwjgl?

Tags: java, 3d, lwjgl

So I have very little experience using lwjgl and was wonrdering where I could find tutorials for making 3d worlds using it...

I need to have stuff like a floor, roof, walls, and the ability to move in this area.
Please help.

Answer (score 6):

[An excellent modern tutorial on using OpenGL3.](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/)

**EDIT:** [New link.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150225192611/http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html)

**EDIT:** [Java specific tutorials (but OpenGL2)](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial)

Comment: thats C++ I need Java...

Comment: The concepts and 95% of the function calls are identical.

Comment: I've added a link to java specific tutorials now but you won't be learning the newer way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

LWJGL's [own Wiki](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) has pretty good series of tutorials right on the front page. Note that creating actual graphics assets, both models and textures is a whole different thing than *"just"* progamming the game around a game engine.

Answer (score 1):

Great YouTube series on modern lwjgl 3D Engine:

http://www.youtube.com/thebennybox

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) - It's built on top of LWJGL but contains a lot more higher level "game engine" features that could be helpful in constructing a 3D world.

LWJGL is much more low level - so it's great if you just want direct, fast access to OpenGL functionality, but you will have to pretty much build your game engine yourself.